# Can Anti-virus affect device performance?

Tags: performance, antivirus

I have installed some anti-viruses on my device, and since then I am feeling that the performance of the device is quite slow, and when I uninstall them the device works fine, and the device starts heating so quickely. So is this because of Apps from the Market or this issue is with my device.

Comment: Try using avast. I used to use it. You can schedule scans in the middle of the night so that they don't bother you too much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All antivirus applications on all platforms will impact the performance of the device.
This is because they intercept your actions and check them for unwanted effects.

You say you have installed anti-viruses - plural.  If you install more than one such application on any device they will start to check upon each other.  This will have a significant cumulative affect which will be immediately noticeable.
If you have installed more than one, then uninstall in the reverse order of installation.

Comment: Exactly, including the last one. The use of those is questionable at best. If you want to keep one of them, don't rely on it and think yourself safe; there are plenty of reports on the tech press how easy it is to circumvent/fool them. So there's only 2 things an AV app can promise: using storage, and having influence on performance. Everything else are nice to have side-effects :)

Comment: Thank you for this information, the information is helpful, can see improvement in the performance :)